# Reputation stuck at 1

Tags: bug, status-norepro, reputation

I've noticed that my meta reputation is stuck at 1 at the moment (not a huge problem for me, but weird).  Has anyone else noticed this?  I've received upvotes to answers, linked my accounts and I'm stuck at measly 1.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

The no-repro is the number next to your name which is non-one. :)

Answer (score 1):

How much rep in the account you're linking from?  I think you have to have 200 to get the 100 for linking.

Check the questions you've answered and had upvoted.  Are they all Community Wiki?

Check your rep now.  I've been puzzled by rep not going up before, so I'm upvoting this question.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your [user page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4640/deeksy), the only [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26109/what-would-you-do-if-stack-overflow-is-down-for-one-day/26112#26112) you've received upvotes for (besides this question) is a *community wiki* answer, so those upvotes didn't generate rep for you.

And what Jeff said (you got rep just fine from an upvote for this question). :)

Answer (score -2):

Looks like I have / had the same problem. The fist upvote I got on an [answer a while ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423447/which-actor-model-library-framework-for-python-and-erlang-like/9410357#9410357) also didn't give me any reputation. Now I got my first reputation, which allowed me to post here at all, with an upvote of a question. This bug would be especially tricky, as people experiencing this problem mostly couldn't even complain about it here.

Comment: The post you linked to is also marked "community wiki", which means upvotes on it do not award reputation. So yes, you're running into the same situation, but it's not a bug.

Comment: Ok, nice to know, thanks! In that case I'd suggest to add some remark in brackets on the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) page. I was actively searching for an explanation, why there was no reputation awarded, but didn't find anything. The whole community wiki thing was not on my radar. When it influences something so essential as the reputation system, I think it won't hurt to mention it in the faq, too.